# How to apply OR filters to a java.util.stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List`:

```
List<String> mylist=Arrays.asList("Abla","Tbla","Cbla");
```

I have 2 filters prepared for my stream:

```
Predicate<String> startswith_A= s-> s.startsWith("A");
Predicate<String> startswith_T= s-> s.startsWith("T");
```

Following example filters for "A":

```
mylist.stream().filter(startswith_A).forEach(mystring -> {
    System.out.println("filtered : " + mystring);
});
```

How can I apply the same for a filter "A" or "T"?

Something like:

```
mylist.stream().filter(startswith_A || startswith_T).forEach(mystring -> {
    System.out.println("filtered : " + mystring);
});
```

I don't want to create a new predicate like:

```
Predicate<String> startswith_A_or_T= s-> s.startsWith("T") || s.startsWith("A");
```

How can I do this with 2 seperate `Predicate`s?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: Why anonymous function doesn't fit your requirements? mylist.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("A") || s.startsWith("T")).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply use [`.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or-java.util.function.Predicate-) between the 2 `Predicates`:

```
mylist.stream()
      .filter(startswith_A.or(startswith_T))
      .forEach(mystring -> { System.out.println("filtered : " + mystring); });
```

Result:

```
filtered : Abla
filtered : Tbla
```